# How to sum two range vectors in VBA?

Tags: excel, vba

I have two vectors of Sheets:

```
vec1 = Sheets("1").Range("C2:C13")
vec2 = Sheets("2").Range("B2:B13")
```

How to sum them?

```
vec3 = vec1 + vec2
```

-doesn't work.

P.S. I want to have result like this:

```
1 + 1 = 2
1 + 2 = 3
1 + 3 = 4

Range 1 = [1,1,1]
Range 2 = [1,2,3]
Range 3 = [2,3,4]
```

Comment: Loop the arrays and put the result of summing each element in a new array.

Comment: Can it be solved without looping?

Comment: Why? Looping is fast and easy.

Comment: Can you please show how to loop in my situation?

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/fornext-statement and https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/fornext-statement

Answer (score 0):

You can loop the two original arrays and store the sum of each respective element in a new array:

```
Dim newVec As Variant
ReDim newVec(1 to Ubound(vec1, 1))

Dim i As Long
For i = 1 To Ubound(vec1, 1)
    newVec(i) = vec1(i, 1) + vec2(i, 1)
Next
```

Note that `vec1` and `vec2` are 2D arrays (and one-based), while `newVec` in the above approach is a 1D array (but can easily be made a 2D array).

Comment: I don't understand why it doesn't work - i get all the values the same